# Adjusting mysql to work with 10,000+ tables

Tags: mysql

Hey,
I need to adjust one of our mysql (5.1 on RH5.8) servers to work with over 10K tables, I don't see any problem for mysql to handle 10-20K tables but I'm sure some changes to it's cnf file are needed.

The only thing I've added to my.cnf file is `table_open_cache=20000`

I'm using InnoDB storage engine, and not using query cache. 
**Is there anything else I am missing?**

Thanks

Comment: there is probably some normalization issues in that thing...  that might be missing. :)

Comment: Are you really sure that you need 10,000+ tables?

Comment: Without using wizardry, it will be difficult to give an accurate answer to such a vague question...

Comment: The nature of this server\application is unique, and it must use around 15K tables. how is the question vague? what details are missing?
Your question was vague Mr Jocelyn.

Comment: maybe you could use some caching on your web application (it is not really specified what application are we talking about but probably it is a web application) i mean memcached or redis server to reduce the queries sent to the mysql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB stores all tables in a single file by default so if you plan on your tables being large, you may hit an OS limit on file sizes, otherwise there isn't really any problem or performance issue with having that many tables.  If you are going to store large amounts of data, check your OS file size limits and see if you need to use the option `innodb_file_per_table` so each table goes in its own file.

Going from what you have now to wanting 10k+ tables doesn't really have any specific configuration changes just for dealing with that many tables.

I'd recommend reading over the MySQL reference manual on the following InnoDB topics: [Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-configuration.html), [Disk I/O and File Space Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-disk-management.html), [Tuning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-tuning-troubleshooting.html), and [Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html) to see if you need to change your configuration or application based on information from those sections.  Perhaps the section most valuable would be the tuning section.

If you plan on creating and dropping lots of tables that grow to a reasonable size, you may want to use the file per table option so your tablespace is less fragmented.

As others have said, there may be a way to structure your data such that you don't need 10-15,000 tables, but can use proper indexing to put a lot of that table data into a single table.  Impossible to say without knowing what you are storing and why that many tables are needed.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, innodb_file_per_table is already enabled.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helped.  If you had any specific concerns feel free to ask for clarification.  But we used to have a database with over 10k tables and no issues before we consolidated it into a single, large table which was much easier to manage.